How to replace <a linktype="page"></a> with <Link to=""></Link> in Wagtail?
Wagtail rewrite handlers allows to expand internal links adding custom HTML attributes, but will not allow to change the closing </a> tag.
I want to replace internal link in Wagtail Richtext to integrate it with React Router.
<a linktype="page" id="5">NAME</a> should be transformed to:
<Link to="/path/to/page">NAME</Link>
I tried to write a custom link handler:
@classmethod
def expand_db_attributes(cls, attrs):
    page = cls.get_instance(attrs)
    return f'<Link to="/pages/{page.uuid}">{page.title}</Link>'

but this will result in:
<Link to="/path/to/page">PAGE NAME</Link>PAGE NAME</a>
as you can see, the original </a> closing tag is preserved, together with a duplicate page name.
